# Scp remote files to the local

Tags: git, scp

I could copy the archive to the server from local using:

```
scp forum.tar.gz root@servername:/root/
```

However, when I tried to send from server to the local

```
[root@iz2ze9wve43n2nyuvmsfx5z ~]# scp draft.md root@localhot:/
ssh: Could not resolve hostname localhot: Name or service not known
lost connection
```

How could I get this job done,
Should I must depend the github to commit and pull?

Comment: On what machine is the second command executed? You misspelled "localhost", and if you really meant `localhost` then the file would be copied to the local host, not to a remote system. You should be able to just reverse the arguments of the first command (well, almost, you will have to specify the filename on the remote host) to copy the file back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname localhot: Name or service not known
```

First, you've misspelled `localhost`.

Second, in this command, `localhost` means the host the `scp` command is currently running on.

If you use

```
scp forum.tar.gz root@servername:/root/
```

to copy a file from the current directory on the local system to `/root/forum.tar.gz` on the server, then

```
scp root@servername:/root/draft.md .
```

will copy the file `/root/draft.md` from the server to the current directory (`.`) on the local system.

Since `/root` is presumably the home directory of the root user, you can even shorten the second command to:

```
scp root@servername:draft.md .
```

When specifying a source or destination name for `scp`, a colon (`:`) in the name means that you're specifying a pathname on some remote host. If there is no slash (`/`) after the colon, the remote pathname is relative to the remote user's home directory; if there is a slash after the colon, it will be an absolute path.